# Let $X ∼ \operatorname{Uniform}(−1,1)$ and $Y=X^2$. Find the $\operatorname{CDF}$ and $\operatorname{PDF}$ of $Y$.

Tags: probability-distributions, continuous-variables

I have some questions about the solution of Example 4.8 from [Probability Course](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter4/4_1_3_functions_continuous_var.php):

> First, we note that $R_Y=[0,1]$. As usual, we start with the CDF. For y∈[0,1], we have

> $F_Y(y) = P(Y≤y) = P(X^2≤y) = P(−√y≤X≤√y) $

> $=\frac{√y−(−√y)}{1−(−1)}$, since $X∼\operatorname{Uniform}(−1,1)$

> $=√y.$

...

\begin{equation}   f_Y(y)=F'_Y(y)=\begin{cases}
     \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}, & for & \text{$0 \leq y \leq 1$}.\\
     0, & otherwise.\\   
\end{cases} \end{equation}

My questions are:

1. Where does $=\frac{√y−(−√y)}{1−(−1)}$ comes from? Could it be $\int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}} dy$?
2. Why do we have $\geq 0$ for the CDF? Should $\frac{1}{2\sqrt 0}$ invalid?

Thank you so much!

Comment: With regard to your second question (which I assume to be about the _PDF_, not the _CDF_), you can write it as $0 < y \leq 1$ if you want.  Writing $0 \leq y \leq 1$ is somewhat sloppy, but it's also relatively harmless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $(a,b) \subset (-1,1)$ we have $P(a\leq X\leq b)=\frac  {b-a} 2$. Since $X$ is  uniformly distributed in $(-1,1)$ the probability that $X$ takes values in $(a,b)$ is the length of the interval $(a,b)$ divided by the length of the entire interval $(-1,1)$ ( the latter being $(1)-(-1)=2$). For $a=-\sqrt y, b=\sqrt y$ this is also equal to $\frac 1 2  \int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}} dy$.

$Y=X^{2}$ is always non-negative and $Y$ takes values in $[0,1)$.